# Golang BigInt division

Tags: go, division, biginteger, bignum

I have a problem with function and i don't understand why it happen. The problem is: i have a big number, but when i'm trying to make some operations of division - I have zeros.
The code is:

```
for {

        fmt.Println("number is", number)
        // key := number % 10
        key := number.Mod(number, big.NewInt(10))
        fmt.Println("key", key)
        // number = number / 10
        first := new(big.Int).Div(number, big.NewInt(10))
        fmt.Println("first ", first)

        number = first
        fmt.Println(number) //number = 0 always as a fisrt variable too
... }
```

The example of exit is:

```
number is 6689502913449127057588118054090372586752746333138029810295671352301633557244962989366874165271984981308157637893214090552534408589408121859898481114389650005964960521256960000000000000000000000000000
key  0
first  0
0
```

Number is getting on correnctly, Mod operation is seems correctly too. Div operation is not. What the point is? How can i calculate basic divisions of big numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
key := number.Mod(number, big.NewInt(10))
```

You call `number.Mod()` which is [`Int.Mod()`](https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Int.Mod) which **modifies** the receiver which is `number`, it sets it to the modulus which is `0`, so after this `number` will be zeroed.

You have to use a new `big.Int`, just as you used for the `Div()` operation:

```
key := new(big.Int).Mod(number, big.NewInt(10))
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/yCvSQv4hHGo).

Also note that there is [`Int.DivMod()`](https://pkg.go.dev/math/big#Int.DivMod) which performs both these 2 operations (`Div()` and `Mod()`).

Also note that to speed up your loop, you should create and reuse `*big.Int` values, and not create and throw them away in each iteration. The most trivial is to create and reuse `10`:

```
var ten = big.NewInt(10)
```

Also create and reuse values for the mod and div results.